# How to add pattern to polygon in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a pattern to a polygon using javascript, but the pattern is not showing.

I tried to accomplish this by appending SVG tags.

```html
    <svg tabindex="1" style="width: 175px; height: 216.506px;">
      <polygon points="25,0 75,0 100,43 75,86 25,86 0,43" tabindex="1" hex-row="0" hex-column="0" fill="gray"></polygon>
      <polygon points="100,44 150,44 175,87 150,130 100,130 75,87" tabindex="1" hex-row="0" hex-column="1"  fill="gray"></polygon>
      <polygon points="25,87 75,87 100,130 75,173 25,173 0,130" tabindex="1" hex-row="1" hex-column="0" fill="gray"></polygon>
      <polygon id="chosen-one" points="100,130 150,130 175,173 150,216 100,216 75,173" tabindex="1" hex-row="1" hex-column="1" fill=""></polygon>
    </svg>
```

```js
var def = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");

var pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
pattern.setAttribute('id', 'image1');
pattern.setAttribute('x', '0%');
pattern.setAttribute('y', '0%');
pattern.setAttribute('height', '100%');
pattern.setAttribute('width', '100%');
pattern.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 64 64');

var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute('x', '0%');
image.setAttribute('y', '0%');
image.setAttribute('width', '64');
image.setAttribute('height', '64');
image.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Software/labo.png');

pattern.appendChild(image)
def.appendChild(pattern)

$('svg')[0].append(def);

var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttribute('href', '#hexfield');
use.setAttribute('fill', 'yellow');
$('svg')[0].append(use)

var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttribute('href', '#hexfield');
use.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#image1)');
$('svg')[0].append(use)

    // element that will be wrapped
var el = document.querySelector('#chosen-one');

// create wrapper container
var wrapper = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'hexfield')

// insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree
el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);

// move el into wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(el);
```

I expected it to look like this:

[image: yellow with image]

But the image part is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no valid `<img>`-tag within a `<svg>`-tag, so you have to change this line:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
```

into:

```
var image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","image");
```

Furthermore you should put an encoding-declaration within your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

otherwise a svg-element does not know how to interpret the signs when they are not ascii-coded and there is an ugly error afterwards at least on FF.

Hope this helps you!

P.s.

And IE11 does not know `append`-method with HTML-Nodes:

```
$('svg')[0].append(def)
```

but `appendChild`:

```
$('svg')[0].appendChild(def);
```

---

**Apply one single image-pattern to multiple polygons:**

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

var def = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");

var pattern = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "pattern");
pattern.setAttribute('id', 'image1');
pattern.setAttribute('x', '0%');
pattern.setAttribute('y', '0%');
pattern.setAttribute('height', '100%');
pattern.setAttribute('width', '100%');
pattern.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 64 64');

var image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
image.setAttribute('x', '0%');
image.setAttribute('y', '0%');
image.setAttribute('width', '64');
image.setAttribute('height', '64');
image.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imod/512/Software/labo.png');

pattern.appendChild(image)
def.appendChild(pattern)

svg.appendChild(def);

// element that will be wrapped
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(number) {
    var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.setAttribute('href', '#hexfield' + number);
    use.setAttribute('fill', 'yellow');
    svg.appendChild(use);

    var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    use.setAttribute('href', '#hexfield' + number);
    use.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#image1)');
    svg.appendChild(use);

    var poly = document.querySelector('#poly-' + number);
    // create wrapper container
    var wrapper = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'hexfield' + number);
    // insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree
    poly.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, poly);
    // move el into wrapper
    wrapper.appendChild(poly);
});
```

```html
<svg tabindex="1" style="width: 175px; height: 216.506px;">
    <polygon id="poly-1" points="25,0 75,0 100,43 75,86 25,86 0,43" tabindex="1" hex-row="0" hex-column="0" fill=""></polygon>
    <polygon id="poly-2" points="100,44 150,44 175,87 150,130 100,130 75,87" tabindex="1" hex-row="0" hex-column="1"  fill=""></polygon>
    <polygon id="poly-3" points="25,87 75,87 100,130 75,173 25,173 0,130" tabindex="1" hex-row="1" hex-column="0" fill=""></polygon>
    <polygon id="poly-4" points="100,130 150,130 175,173 150,216 100,216 75,173" tabindex="1" hex-row="1" hex-column="1" fill=""></polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: It is possible to add the image to multiple polygons?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.